# How to insert all of the Treeview items into sqllite3 Database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

geniuses
I am trying to insert all Treeview rows into the sqllite3 database, and instead of that, it only inserts the last row.

I have tried the following:

```
def buying_addcheck(self):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
    self.cursorObj = self.conn.cursor()
    self.checkid += 1
    self.buying_checkspaymenttree.insert("", 'end', values=(
    self.buying_check_date_var.get(), self.buying_check_value_var.get(),
    self.buying_check_num_var.get(),self.checkid))

     
     def checks_db(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
        self.cursorObj = self.conn.cursor()
        # Values variable from Treeview and other widget's
        sellingcarsinfchecks = (
            (
                self.checkid, self.makevar.get(), self.sellernamevar.get(),
                self.Buyingdate_var.get(),
                self.cashepayments.get(),
                self.buying_check_num_var.get(), self.buying_check_value_var.get(), self.buying_check_date_var.get(),
                self.buying_nocheckpic))
        self.cursorObj.execute(
            """INSERT INTO cars_buying_checksonly(checkid, carmake, sellername, buyingdate, entirepaymentmethod, checknum, checkvalue, checkdate, checkpic)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
            sellingcarsinfchecks)
        self.conn.commit()
```

Question: How to insert all of the Treeview items into  sqllite3 Database.

Comment: You need to go through all the items in the treeview.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for your reply, I appreciate your continued cooperation, to be honest, this is my problem and I don't know how to do it, I think for loop might help but I don't know the exact solution.

Comment: I think what you need is to call `checks_db()` inside `buying_addcheck()`, then you don't need to go through the treevew.

Comment: @awc1668 I have tried to call self.checks_db() inside buying_addcheck() after inserting (self.buying_checkspaymenttree.insert) values, but it doesn't work.
 what I am trying to do is to use another button to save and insert Treeview items into the sqllite3 database

Comment: And also why is `sellingcarsinfchecks` a nested tuple?

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* means nothing to us.  You need to state clearly what the problem is and show the full traceback if any.  @Delrius it is not a nested tuple as there is no comma inside `))`.

Comment: @acw1668 Oops, missed that due to formatting

Comment: @acw1668 I know that """""It doesn't work""""" MEANS NOTHING  :)

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria is putting sellingcarsinfchecks in a list and using if with for a loop can help?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Adding items from Treeview into self.checksrecords list

Step2: Inserting values from list into DB, by using for loop records in self.checkrecords list

```
def buying_addcheck(self):

     self.checksrecords=[]
     self.checkid += 1
     self.buying_checkspaymenttree.insert("", 'end', values=(
     self.buying_check_date_var.get(), self.buying_check_value_var.get(),
     self.buying_check_num_var.get(), self.checkid,self.makevar.get()))

     for child in self.buying_checkspaymenttree.get_children():
       self.checksrecords.append(self.buying_checkspaymenttree.item(child) 
       ["values"])
    
   
  def checks_db(self):
      self.conn = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
      self.cursorObj = self.conn.cursor()

      for self.checksrecords in self.checksrecords:
          self.cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO cars_buying_checksonly_demo 
          (checkdate, checkvalue, checknum, checkid,carmake)values(?,?,?,?,?)",                            
          (self.checksrecords[0],self.checksrecords[1],,self.checksrecords[2],
           self.checksrecords[3],self.checksrecords[4])) 
           
        self.conn.commit()
```